# Why my scanner is reading " 'B' and \n" instead of "B" when "\n" is set as delimiter?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I´ve created a simple program that communicates a client and a server via TCP. The code is simple and I have done it using sockets(I don´t have problems related to this, I mean you don´t need to know about sockets to help me)
In the part of the code which is highlighted I need to ask the user to write a letter which represents an action that the server will do, but I don´t know why when I write, for example, B + enter, the scanner reads B + enter (I have select enter (\n) as a delimiter). I have solved it using a substring but I don´t like that. Can anyone tell me why the scanner read "B + \n" instead of "B"?. Thanks in advance. Here you can see the code: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycSA5.png)

Anyway, I write here the part of the code where the troubles are:

```
...
 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
 sc.useDelimiter("\n");
 System.out.println("Por favor especifique el campo opción (letra): ");
//(here I write B and I press enter)
opcion = sc.next();
//(here the scanner reads both B and \n I have to write the next line to solve the problem)
opcion = opcion.substring(0, 1);//(This is what i want to solve)
...
```

Comment: Try `sc.useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator());`. Maybe your computer uses a different line ending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use opcion = sc.nextLine();
That way it will ignore the \n and give you the string that you need.

Comment: FYI, when you do that, you don't need to call sc.useDelimiter...

Comment: Thank you, It works and its better than using \n as the delimiter. Anyway, I think that what I did should work. Do you know what could be the problem?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but it seems to me the scanner is meant to be used with those utility methods nextLine, nextInt etc. Why reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: Thank you, I agree with you but I´m too curious :).